# o.minimize() does not give me the minimal solution

Tags: z3, z3py

In my last post i got this min(max()) function:

```
def maxi(a,b):
  return If(a>=b,a,b)

a = 0
for y in zip(*time): #time is a list with many rows and columns
  z = sum(y)         #z receives the sum of the columns
  a = maxi(a,z)     

o.minimize(a)
```

Info: Each variable in my matrix can have the value 7.08 or 0

My problem is the following:

```
-> If I put a=0, I will never get a solution

-> If I put a=50, I will get a solution but I will never get the best solution.
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thx!

Comment: *"I will never get a solution"* = *"takes too much time"*  ???

Comment: Last time i left the program run for 30 min and he was stil running...

Comment: i will let him run more time and then i will let you know what i got

Comment: If you already let it run for 30 mins with no result, I wouldn't hold my breath. Obviously, the problem is beyond capacity. Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can try to help.

Comment: The constant value you put in your model acts as a barrier for the minimization process, once every other `sum()` is below this value it can stop.